# C++ decltype in template inner class

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, decltype

My problem is illustrated by the example below:

```
#include <vector>

    template <class T>
    class TestNest{
    public:
        std::vector<T> m_list;
        class InsideNest{
            const TestNest<T>* m_test;
            decltype(m_test->m_list.begin()) m_iter;
        public:
            InsideNest(const TestNest<T>* source)
                :m_test(source)
                ,m_iter(source->m_list.begin())
            {}
        };
    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestNest<int> outside;
    TestNest<int>::InsideNest inside(&outside);
}
```

the part that does not compile (at least not in MSVC2013) is `decltype(m_test->m_list.begin())`. Any idea how I can get around the problem?

EDIT: changed code to show main() and #include

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: error C2227: left of '->m_list' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Comment: In VS2015 everything is OK. Please show the includes.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I can't just use `std::vector<T>::iterator` as my real class is more complex than the one above

Comment: try cbegin instead of begin...

Comment: GCC (minGW) accepted without complaint - after fixing `m_iter(source->m_list.begin())`

Comment: [Cannot reproduce with g++](http://cpp.sh/2y4sn)

Comment: Nope, constness is not the issue, cbegin doesn't solve. My suspect is that it's a compiler limitation. Anyone can suggest workarounds?

Comment: Could you `typedef` the iterator in the outer class and use that one in the inner?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 compiles this fine if you change `m_iter(source->begin())` to `m_iter(source->m_list.begin())` which isn't the line you are reporting as causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback everyone.

even `std::vector<T> m_list; using IteratorType = decltype(m_list.cbegin());`

doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the issue. This is a shortcoming of MSVC2013. It will resolve `decltype()` before "working out" the full type of members so inside decltype any access to methods is a compiler error.
Even using global template functions (e.g. `decltype(std::begin(m_list))`) won't work.
Other, more modern, compilers work.